# Keras Regression model loss: nan. How to fix it?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I followed the code in the book 'hands-on machine learning with scikit-learn and tensorflow' to build a multiple outputs neural network in Keras. However, I keep getting a loss: nan output. How to fix this?

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing

housing = fetch_cawwwlifornia_housing()

X_train_full, X_test, y_train_full, y_test = train_test_split(
    housing.data, housing.target)

X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(
    X_train_full, y_train_full)

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_valid_scaled = scaler.transform(X_valid)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)

X_train_A, X_train_B = X_train[:, :5], X_train[:, 2:]
X_valid_A, X_valid_B = X_valid[:, :5], X_valid[:, 2:]
X_test_A, X_test_B = X_test[:, :5], X_test[:, 2:]
X_new_A, X_new_B = X_test_A[:3], X_test_B[:3]

input_A = keras.layers.Input(shape=[5], name="wide_input")
input_B = keras.layers.Input(shape=[6], name="deep_input")
hidden1 = keras.layers.Dense(30, activation="relu")(input_B)
hidden2 = keras.layers.Dense(30, activation="relu")(hidden1)
concat = keras.layers.concatenate([input_A, hidden2])
output = keras.layers.Dense(1, name="main_output")(concat)
aux_output = keras.layers.Dense(1, name="aux_output")(hidden2)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_A, input_B],
                           outputs=[output, aux_output])
model.compile(loss=["mse", "mse"], loss_weights=[0.9, 0.1], optimizer="sgd")

history = model.fit(
    [X_train_A, X_train_B], [y_train, y_train], epochs=20,
    validation_data=([X_valid_A, X_valid_B], [y_valid, y_valid]))
```

**output**

```
Train on 11610 samples, validate on 3870 samples
Epoch 1/20
11610/11610 [==============================] - 6s 525us/sample - loss: nan - main_output_loss: nan - aux_output_loss: nan - val_loss: nan - val_main_output_loss: nan - val_aux_output_loss: nan
Epoch 2/20
11610/11610 [==============================] - 4s 336us/sample - loss: nan - main_output_loss: nan - aux_output_loss: nan - val_loss: nan - val_main_output_loss: nan - val_aux_output_loss: nan
Epoch 3/20
11610/11610 [==============================] - 5s 428us/sample - loss: nan - main_output_loss: nan - aux_output_loss: nan - val_loss: nan - val_main_output_loss: nan - val_aux_output_loss: nan
Epoch 4/20
11610/11610 [==============================] - 5s 424us/sample - loss: nan - main_output_loss: nan - aux_output_loss: nan - val_loss: nan - val_main_output_loss: nan - val_aux_output_loss: nan
Epoch 5/20
11610/11610 [==============================] - 5s 414us/sample - loss: nan - main_output_loss: nan - aux_output_loss: nan - val_loss: nan - val_main_output_loss: nan - val_aux_output_loss: nan
Epoch 6/20
11610/11610 [==============================] - 5s 400us/sample - loss: nan - main_output_loss: nan - aux_output_loss: nan - val_loss: nan - val_main_output_loss: nan - val_aux_output_loss: nan
Epoch 7/20
11610/11610 [==============================] - 5s 392us/sample - loss: nan - main_output_loss: nan - aux_output_loss: nan - val_loss: nan - val_main_output_loss: nan - val_aux_output_loss: nan
Epoch 8/20
11610/11610 [==============================] - 5s 405us/sample - loss: nan - main_output_loss: nan - aux_output_loss: nan - val_loss: nan - val_main_output_loss: nan - val_aux_output_loss: nan
Epoch 9/20
11610/11610 [==============================] - 4s 369us/sample - loss: nan - main_output_loss: nan - aux_output_loss: nan - val_loss: nan - val_main_output_loss: nan - val_aux_output_loss: nan
Epoch 10/20
11610/11610 [==============================] - 5s 405us/sample - loss: nan - main_output_loss: nan - aux_output_loss: nan - val_loss: nan - val_main_output_loss: nan - val_aux_output_loss: nan
Epoch 11/20
11610/11610 [==============================] - 5s 423us/sample - loss: nan - main_output_loss: nan - aux_output_loss: nan - val_loss: nan - val_main_output_loss: nan - val_aux_output_loss: nan
Epoch 12/20
11610/11610 [==============================] - 5s 454us/sample - loss: nan - main_output_loss: nan - aux_output_loss: nan - val_loss: nan - val_main_output_loss: nan - val_aux_output_loss: nan
Epoch 13/20
11610/11610 [==============================] - 4s 380us/sample - loss: nan - main_output_loss: nan - aux_output_loss: nan - val_loss: nan - val_main_output_loss: nan - val_aux_output_loss: nan
Epoch 14/20
11610/11610 [==============================] - 5s 446us/sample - loss: nan - main_output_loss: nan - aux_output_loss: nan - val_loss: nan - val_main_output_loss: nan - val_aux_output_loss: nan
Epoch 15/20
11610/11610 [==============================] - 5s 411us/sample - loss: nan - main_output_loss: nan - aux_output_loss: nan - val_loss: nan - val_main_output_loss: nan - val_aux_output_loss: nan
Epoch 16/20
11610/11610 [==============================] - 5s 457us/sample - loss: nan - main_output_loss: nan - aux_output_loss: nan - val_loss: nan - val_main_output_loss: nan - val_aux_output_loss: nan
Epoch 17/20
11610/11610 [==============================] - 5s 415us/sample - loss: nan - main_output_loss: nan - aux_output_loss: nan - val_loss: nan - val_main_output_loss: nan - val_aux_output_loss: nan
Epoch 18/20
11610/11610 [==============================] - 5s 411us/sample - loss: nan - main_output_loss: nan - aux_output_loss: nan - val_loss: nan - val_main_output_loss: nan - val_aux_output_loss: nan
Epoch 19/20
11610/11610 [==============================] - 5s 388us/sample - loss: nan - main_output_loss: nan - aux_output_loss: nan - val_loss: nan - val_main_output_loss: nan - val_aux_output_loss: nan
Epoch 20/20
11610/11610 [==============================] - 4s 363us/sample - loss: nan - main_output_loss: nan - aux_output_loss: nan - val_loss: nan - val_main_output_loss: nan - val_aux_output_loss: nan
```

Comment: What optimizer and loss function are you using?

Comment: You left out the `model.compile` line which is funny enough probably showing the cause of your issue. Using Adam with LR 0.001 and MSE loss I can train the network just fine. Your learning rate was probably too high.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I did run with model.compile, but i just forgot to copy to the post.

Comment: I did run with model.compile, but i just forgot to copy to my post

Comment: I tried to run with Adam, but the loss is still nan

Comment: Can you add a colab link because I can't reproduce your issue. The code works fine for me.

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jm1r7BvE4hWFWzXJMeXrHo8DLs-kNadl?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the comment, very often a NaN is caused by learning rates that are too high or similar instabilities during Optimization which causes exploding gradients. This can also be prevented by setting `clipnorm`. Setting up an optimizer with a proper learning rate:

```
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001, clipnorm=1.)
model.compile(loss=["mse", "mse"], loss_weights=[0.9, 0.1], optimizer=opt)
```

leads to better training in your notebook:

```
Epoch 1/20
363/363 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1547.7197 - main_output_loss: 967.1940 - aux_output_loss: 6772.4609 - val_loss: 19.9807 - val_main_output_loss: 20.0967 - val_aux_output_loss: 18.9365
Epoch 2/20
363/363 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 13.2916 - main_output_loss: 14.0150 - aux_output_loss: 6.7812 - val_loss: 14.6868 - val_main_output_loss: 14.5820 - val_aux_output_loss: 15.6298
Epoch 3/20
363/363 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 11.0539 - main_output_loss: 11.6683 - aux_output_loss: 5.5244 - val_loss: 10.5564 - val_main_output_loss: 10.2116 - val_aux_output_loss: 13.6594
Epoch 4/20
363/363 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 7.4646 - main_output_loss: 7.7688 - aux_output_loss: 4.7269 - val_loss: 13.2672 - val_main_output_loss: 11.5239 - val_aux_output_loss: 28.9570
Epoch 5/20
363/363 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 5.6873 - main_output_loss: 5.8091 - aux_output_loss: 4.5909 - val_loss: 5.0464 - val_main_output_loss: 4.5089 - val_aux_output_loss: 9.8839
```

It's not performing amazingly but you'll have to optimize all hyperparameters from here to tweak it to satisfaction.

You can also observe the effect of clipnorm by using SGD as you initially intended :

```
opt = keras.optimizers.SGD(0.001, clipnorm=1.)
model.compile(loss=["mse", "mse"], loss_weights=[0.9, 0.1], optimizer=opt)
```

This trains properly. As soon as you remove `clipnorm` however, you will get `NaN`s.